error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'cstr_count_bytes' in flutter project
in context of upgrade version of Android Studio AND Flutter, then my project throw error when I build this.
Error message :
SEVERE: error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'cstr_count_bytes'
SEVERE : error : could not compile `super_native_extensions` (lib) due to previous error [C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\xxxxxxxxx\build\windows\x64\plugins\super_native_extensions\super_native_extensions_plugin_cargokit.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(254,5): error MSB8066: la build personnalis�e de 'C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\xxxxxxxxx\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\f48349bdf7bd8afd1dd98a72eb3ec9de\super_native_extensions.dll.rule;C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\xxxxxxxxx\build\windows\x64\CMakeFiles\ae7c70d23e99463b83dc4ed6f7e31dbb\super_native_extensions_plugin_cargokit.rule;C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\xxxxxxxxx\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\super_native_extensions\windows\CMakeLists.txt' s'est arr�t�e. Code�-1. [C:\PROJECT\ANDROIDStudio\xxxxxxxxx\build\windows\x64\plugins\super_native_extensions\super_native_extensions_plugin_cargokit.vcxproj]
Error: Build process failed.

flutter --version :
Flutter 3.24.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4cf269e36d (8 days ago) • 2024-09-03 14:30:00 -0700
Engine • revision a6bd3f1de1
Tools • Dart 3.5.2 • DevTools 2.37.2

It seems that concern C++ langage compilation.
I already do that without success :
flutter pub cache clean
flutter clean

Do you have an idea how can I resolve this or any way to resolve ?

This is not C++ rather is [tag:dart]

The package 'super_native_extensions' where issue from is a dependency of the 'super_drag_and_drop' package that I use into my flutter project.
It seems that package is compiled with rust
I resolve my issue by update rust env like this :
rustup update

For sure that all fine I cleaned again my project with those :
flutter clean

flutter pub cache clean

Now, when I re-run my build project all run correctly
